# Сортировка list-a на стороне клиента (Java ee, jstl, jsp, js)

Tags: javascript, сортировка, java-ee, jsp, jstl

Изучаю java-ee. Возник вопрос.

Вот мой класс Teacher

```
public class Teacher {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public Teacher(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

на странице jsp я получаю java.util.List этих самых объектов вот таким образом и вывожу на экран этот список

```
<table border="1">
  <c:forEach items="${requestScope.teachers}" var="t">
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>${t.lastName}</p>
              <p>${t.firstName}</p>
              <p>${t.email}</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Могу ли я как-то на стороне клиента (на самой jsp) с помощью js отсортировать этот список(скажем порядок A-Z) и вывести его на экран?? 
Есть ли вообще какие-то способы сделать это на стороне клиента?

Comment: Во-первых, JSP работает на стороне сервера. Во-вторых, по какому из полей именно вы хотите сортировать?

Comment: По firstName хотел

Comment: Jsp работает только на сервере, на клиенте придётся получать массив всех этих элементов в JavaScriptt все просматривать, переставлять , да и зачем если можно в методе getTeachers() сортировать их до выдачи любым доступным способом.Если хотите именно по имени, то копайте в сторону Comparator и Comparable